# How can I optimize this MYSQL Script For many Records?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query, scripting, query-performance

I have This script by Helping @lukstorms ,

```
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_words;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_words (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  words text NOT NULL
);

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_words_unfolded;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_words_unfolded (
  word varchar(500) NOT NULL ,
  id int unsigned NOT NULL,
  KEY (word)
) row_format=dynamic;


-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_wordlist;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_wordlist (
  wordid serial primary key,
  word text NOT NULL
);

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_wordids;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_wordids (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL,
  wordid int unsigned NOT NULL,
  idlist text,
  KEY (id),
  KEY (wordid)
);

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_result;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_result (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  words text NOT NULL
);

-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_nums;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_nums (n int unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
TRUNCATE TABLE test_nums;
INSERT INTO test_nums (n) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20),(21),(22),(23),(24),(25),(26),(27),(28),(29),(30),(31),(32),(33),(34),(35),(36),(37),(38),(39),(40),(41),(42),(43),(44),(45),(46),(47),(48),(49),(50),(51),(52),(53),(54),(55),(56),(57),(58),(59),(60),(61),(62),(63),(64),(65),(66),(67),(68),(69),(70),(71),(72),(73),(74),(75),(76),(77),(78),(79),(80);

TRUNCATE TABLE test_words;
INSERT INTO test_words (id, words) VALUES
(1  ,'!1i7y41DiNlK2;qCj5n1i7y;41DiNlK2qCj5n1;i7y41DiNlK2qC;j5n1i7y;41DiNlK2qCj5n1;i7y41DiNlK2qCj5n'),
(2  ,'!mVHfE9O8ZNdR;P5DsmmmVH;fE9O8ZNdRP5Dsmmm;VHfE9O8ZNdRP5D;smmmV;HfE9O8ZNdRP5Dsmmm;VHfE9O8ZNdRP5Dsmm'),
(3  ,'!W5rpiQgtYxF;5MyfF5W5rp;iQgtYxF5MyfF5W;5rpiQgtYxF5My;fF5W5rp;iQgtYxF5MyfF5W;5rpiQgtYxF5MyfF5'),
(4  ,'!XeMV3WTIxHD1d;45KUXeMV;3WTIxHD1d45KUX;eMV3WTIxHD1d45;KUXeMV;3WTIxHD1d45KUX;eMV3WTIxHD1d45KU'),
(5  ,'!ptwj11ir8XrwQ6;g2zqsptwj1;1ir8XrwQ6g2zqsp;twj11ir8XrwQ6g2;zqsptwj;11ir8XrwQ6g2zqsp;twj11ir8XrwQ6g2zqs'),
(6  ,'!H3W7T6f0PVDIT;outt6nH3W7T;6f0PVDIToutt6nH;3W7T6f0PVDITout;t6nH3W7;T6f0PVDIToutt6nH;3W7T6f0PVDIToutt6n'),
(7  ,'!hiwVTM5hEEft7Q;mPUmWhiwVT;M5hEEft7QmPUmWh;iwVTM5hEEft7QmPU;mWhiwV;TM5hEEft7QmPUmWh;iwVTM5hEEft7QmPUmW'),
(8  ,'!K2rdZkwoycyon;DIJerEK2rd;ZkwoycyonDIJerEK;2rdZkwoycyonDIJ;erEK2rd;ZkwoycyonDIJerEK;2rdZkwoycyonDIJerE'),
(9  ,'!RJOis9hvsD37;qRLvQ6RJOis;9hvsD37qRLvQ6R;JOis9hvsD37qRL;vQ6RJOi;s9hvsD37qRLvQ6R;JOis9hvsD37qRLvQ6'),
(10 ,'!OxP7kULjLD0NlX;h5zWOZOxP7k;ULjLD0NlXh5zWOZO;xP7kULjLD0NlXh5z;WOZOxP7;kULjLD0NlXh5zWOZO;xP7kULjLD0NlXh5zWOZ'),
(11 ,'!4sT7DstFFv8ltE;eoGXUr4sT7D;stFFv8ltEeoGXUr4;sT7DstFFv8ltEeoG;XUr4sT7;DstFFv8ltEeoGXUr4;sT7DstFFv8ltEeoGXUr'),
(12 ,'!TjNmpYiNulMX;TSZQE5TjNm;pYiNulMXTSZQE5T;jNmpYiNulMXTSZ;QE5TjN;mpYiNulMXTSZQE5T;jNmpYiNulMXTSZQE5'),
(13 ,'!VqXYl03xvsplje;rxocY9VqXYl;03xvspljerxocY9V;qXYl03xvspljerxo;cY9VqXY;l03xvspljerxocY9V;qXYl03xvspljerxocY9'),
(14 ,'!YCwOJmqdt9F2hH;7fHx1YCwOJ;mqdt9F2hH7fHx1Y;CwOJmqdt9F2hH7fH;x1YCwO;Jmqdt9F2hH7fHx1Y;CwOJmqdt9F2hH7fHx1'),
(15 ,'!HzU3uRnQNVDP;umKkZIHzU3;uRnQNVDPumKkZIH;zU3uRnQNVDPumK;kZIHzU;3uRnQNVDPumKkZIH;zU3uRnQNVDPumKkZI'),
(16 ,'!2ZRXgL4ZxChgw;2x6S2ZRXg;L4ZxChgw2x6S2;ZRXgL4ZxChgw2;x6S2ZRX;gL4ZxChgw2x6S2;ZRXgL4ZxChgw2x6S'),
(17 ,'!UrzHZyuoWW;uxV9C6UrzH;ZyuoWWuxV9C6U;rzHZyuoWWuxV;9C6Urz;HZyuoWWuxV9C6U;rzHZyuoWWuxV9C6'),
(18 ,'!Rs0venylDKQ0F;xMNK0oRs0ve;nylDKQ0FxMNK0oR;s0venylDKQ0FxMN;K0oRs0v;enylDKQ0FxMNK0oR;s0venylDKQ0FxMNK0o'),
(19 ,'!IldIIIJ6VCCi4;s8W84IldII;IJ6VCCi4s8W84I;ldIIIJ6VCCi4s8;W84IldI;IIJ6VCCi4s8W84I;ldIIIJ6VCCi4s8W84'),
(20 ,'!wywvP28fgNoRQ;j2tN0wywv;P28fgNoRQj2tN0w;ywvP28fgNoRQj2t;N0wyw;vP28fgNoRQj2tN0w;ywvP28fgNoRQj2tN0'),
(21 ,'!ukjYiDksZPJ9LE;yOOSLukjYi;DksZPJ9LEyOOSLu;kjYiDksZPJ9LEyOO;SLukjY;iDksZPJ9LEyOOSLu;kjYiDksZPJ9LEyOOSL'),
(22 ,'!mMJFFrXDTEWL;dk5RmcmMJ;FFrXDTEWLdk5Rmcm;MJFFrXDTEWLdk5;RmcmM;JFFrXDTEWLdk5Rmcm;MJFFrXDTEWLdk5Rmc'),
(23 ,'!VVih1wD0KY2np;cnqGD1VVih;1wD0KY2npcnqGD1;VVih1wD0KY2npcnq;GD1VVi;h1wD0KY2npcnqGD1;VVih1wD0KY2npcnqGD1'),
(24 ,'!9H0sIID54YXD;WUiQtS9H0s;IID54YXDWUiQtS9;H0sIID54YXDWUi;QtS9H0;sIID54YXDWUiQtS9;H0sIID54YXDWUiQtS'),
(25 ,'!Mo8ImqgLr4iv1V;5Yy2yYMo8Im;qgLr4iv1V5Yy2yYM;o8ImqgLr4iv1V5Yy;2yYMo8I;mqgLr4iv1V5Yy2yYM;o8ImqgLr4iv1V5Yy2yY'),
(26 ,'!xlW8tEsewe00m;yKrtxlW8t;Esewe00myKrtx;lW8tEsewe00myK;rtxlW8;tEsewe00myKrtx;lW8tEsewe00myKrt'),
(27 ,'!kCP8ch4KOcKY;My1HZkCP8c;h4KOcKYMy1HZk;CP8ch4KOcKYMy;1HZkCP8;ch4KOcKYMy1HZk;CP8ch4KOcKYMy1HZ'),
(28 ,'!7Vod5Qe2s18Wcr;MtkQCc7Vod5;Qe2s18WcrMtkQCc7;Vod5Qe2s18WcrMtk;QCc7Vod;5Qe2s18WcrMtkQCc7;Vod5Qe2s18WcrMtkQCc'),
(29 ,'!0K6INYcK9Q0Q;ehxlZI0K6IN;YcK9Q0QehxlZI0;K6INYcK9Q0Qehx;lZI0K6I;NYcK9Q0QehxlZI0;K6INYcK9Q0QehxlZI'),
(30 ,'!40ORDrXreOkFGj;sCW6pT40ORD;rXreOkFGjsCW6pT4;0ORDrXreOkFGjsCW;6pT40OR;DrXreOkFGjsCW6pT4;0ORDrXreOkFGjsCW6pT'),
(31 ,'!pn22cfCUk7sJlP;nCQVu3pn22c;fCUk7sJlPnCQVu3p;n22cfCUk7sJlPnCQ;Vu3pn22;cfCUk7sJlPnCQVu3p;n22cfCUk7sJlPnCQVu3'),
(32 ,'!weZk4vDOigRWw;2IgOZweZk4;vDOigRWw2IgOZw;eZk4vDOigRWw2Ig;OZweZk;4vDOigRWw2IgOZw;eZk4vDOigRWw2IgOZ'),
(33 ,'!hZqzmLXDJ1My;SRipnthZqz;mLXDJ1MySRipnth;ZqzmLXDJ1MySRi;pnthZq;zmLXDJ1MySRipnth;ZqzmLXDJ1MySRipnt'),
(34 ,'!9omWuMV731VZw;eU9kEh9omWu;MV731VZweU9kEh9;omWuMV731VZweU9;kEh9omW;uMV731VZweU9kEh9;omWuMV731VZweU9kEh'),
(35 ,'!TmeeWHpnTiR5q;116VtgTmeeW;HpnTiR5q116VtgT;meeWHpnTiR5q116;VtgTmee;WHpnTiR5q116VtgT;meeWHpnTiR5q116Vtg'),
(36 ,'!7w8C5Xs0hwHJqm;iuZ8m7w8C5;Xs0hwHJqmiuZ8m7;w8C5Xs0hwHJqmiu;Z8m7w8C;5Xs0hwHJqmiuZ8m7;w8C5Xs0hwHJqmiuZ8m'),
(37 ,'!TUPSnkpxrPCuw;ZnLlCKTUPS;nkpxrPCuwZnLlCKT;UPSnkpxrPCuwZnL;lCKTUPS;nkpxrPCuwZnLlCKT;UPSnkpxrPCuwZnLlCK'),
(38 ,'!V4kfx3cV0OPg;3GHIXV4kf;x3cV0OPg3GHIXV;4kfx3cV0OPg3G;HIXV4k;fx3cV0OPg3GHIXV;4kfx3cV0OPg3GHIX'),
(39 ,'!1p97s2dc5IeQ;njEr51p97;s2dc5IeQnjEr51;p97s2dc5IeQnj;Er51p9;7s2dc5IeQnjEr51;p97s2dc5IeQnjEr5'),
(40 ,'!OkQHEjQO5dLX;lFc4xCOkQH;EjQO5dLXlFc4xCO;kQHEjQO5dLXlFc;4xCOkQ;HEjQO5dLXlFc4xCO;kQHEjQO5dLXlFc4xC'),
(41 ,'!kLzmTKVXKGGP6s;q2DwDkkLzmT;KVXKGGP6sq2DwDkk;LzmTKVXKGGP6sq2D;wDkkLzm;TKVXKGGP6sq2DwDkk;LzmTKVXKGGP6sq2DwDk'),
(42 ,'!4LN1ZOPGdNvqZ;ITfW94LN1Z;OPGdNvqZITfW94;LN1ZOPGdNvqZIT;fW94LN1;ZOPGdNvqZITfW94;LN1ZOPGdNvqZITfW9'),
(43 ,'!QQKecpk73Hhi;50n7yHQQKec;pk73Hhi50n7yHQ;QKecpk73Hhi50n;7yHQQKe;cpk73Hhi50n7yHQ;QKecpk73Hhi50n7yH'),
(44 ,'!sZTnOtHQqywHs;ewD5NsZTn;OtHQqywHsewD5Ns;ZTnOtHQqywHsewD;5NsZT;nOtHQqywHsewD5Ns;ZTnOtHQqywHsewD5N'),
(45 ,'!i6xS8QT4TUM8wI;odz6ji6xS8;QT4TUM8wIodz6ji;6xS8QT4TUM8wIodz;6ji6xS;8QT4TUM8wIodz6ji;6xS8QT4TUM8wIodz6j'),
(46 ,'!N6V5oSSCQmiks;rX0J9N6V5;oSSCQmiksrX0J9N;6V5oSSCQmiksrX;0J9N6V;5oSSCQmiksrX0J9N;6V5oSSCQmiksrX0J9'),
(47 ,'!mHgLKFf5mO46D;LS50czmHgL;KFf5mO46DLS50czm;HgLKFf5mO46DLS5;0czmHg;LKFf5mO46DLS50czm;HgLKFf5mO46DLS50cz'),
(48 ,'!LgvXdocFztQOXU;lWlcqfLgvXd;ocFztQOXUlWlcqfL;gvXdocFztQOXUlWl;cqfLgvX;docFztQOXUlWlcqfL;gvXdocFztQOXUlWlcqf'),
(49 ,'!7x7dpP86h8Yf;fJtNDF7x7dp;P86h8YffJtNDF7;x7dpP86h8YffJt;NDF7x7d;pP86h8YffJtNDF7;x7dpP86h8YffJtNDF'),
(50 ,'!3F7KsXcsxOJz;j6o7u3F7K;sXcsxOJzj6o7u3;F7KsXcsxOJzj6o;7u3F7K;sXcsxOJzj6o7u3;F7KsXcsxOJzj6o7u'),
(51 ,'!njQLeK6ZxtC9G2;q7fKcJnjQLe;K6ZxtC9G2q7fKcJn;jQLeK6ZxtC9G2q7f;KcJnjQL;eK6ZxtC9G2q7fKcJn;jQLeK6ZxtC9G2q7fKcJ'),
(52 ,'!MP0IG65l6V85o;gOYnMKMP0IG;65l6V85ogOYnMKM;P0IG65l6V85ogOY;nMKMP0I;G65l6V85ogOYnMKM;P0IG65l6V85ogOYnMK'),
(53 ,'!g5uCCirKYxgw;gP4gQWg5uCC;irKYxgwgP4gQWg;5uCCirKYxgwgP4;gQWg5uC;CirKYxgwgP4gQWg;5uCCirKYxgwgP4gQW'),
(54 ,'!uY3PRmvkMqrSg;Ky0Uq7uY3PR;mvkMqrSgKy0Uq7u;Y3PRmvkMqrSgKy0;Uq7uY3P;RmvkMqrSgKy0Uq7u;Y3PRmvkMqrSgKy0Uq7'),
(55 ,'!4JJJekS83VGGo;toKNfY4JJJe;kS83VGGotoKNfY4;JJJekS83VGGotoK;NfY4JJJ;ekS83VGGotoKNfY4;JJJekS83VGGotoKNfY'),
(56 ,'!sw6tmtWc3mHsww;3WRx3sw6tm;tWc3mHsww3WRx3s;w6tmtWc3mHsww3W;Rx3sw6t;mtWc3mHsww3WRx3s;w6tmtWc3mHsww3WRx3'),
(57 ,'!fSjcmnO4FWMLsk;Lcng0CfSjcm;nO4FWMLskLcng0Cf;SjcmnO4FWMLskLcn;g0CfSjc;mnO4FWMLskLcng0Cf;SjcmnO4FWMLskLcng0C'),
(58 ,'!mH3up5F26twSV;1l3gMxmH3up;5F26twSV1l3gMxm;H3up5F26twSV1l3;gMxmH3u;p5F26twSV1l3gMxm;H3up5F26twSV1l3gMx'),
(59 ,'!qEWG2UOxmXKIf;v9mKhCqEWG2;UOxmXKIfv9mKhCq;EWG2UOxmXKIfv9m;KhCqEWG;2UOxmXKIfv9mKhCq;EWG2UOxmXKIfv9mKhC'),
(60 ,'!Zep3Jg60o69k;GL2D0Zep;3Jg60o69kGL2D0;Zep3Jg60o69kGL2;D0Ze;p3Jg60o69kGL2D0;Zep3Jg60o69kGL2D0'),
(61 ,'!Ro5cItK39626iR;lKC0KRo5cI;tK39626iRlKC0KR;o5cItK39626iRlKC;0KRo5c;ItK39626iRlKC0KR;o5cItK39626iRlKC0K'),
(62 ,'!S8UY9k0hJCKIL;MfwXsLS8UY9;k0hJCKILMfwXsLS;8UY9k0hJCKILMfw;XsLS8UY;9k0hJCKILMfwXsLS;8UY9k0hJCKILMfwXsL'),
(63 ,'!cg6xkyMgFRG0H7;rNwJRzcg6xk;yMgFRG0H7rNwJRzc;g6xkyMgFRG0H7rNw;JRzcg6x;kyMgFRG0H7rNwJRzc;g6xkyMgFRG0H7rNwJRz'),
(64 ,'!2IOtXfroj2;XheGmm2I;OtXfroj2XheGmm;2IOtXfroj2Xhe;Gmm2;IOtXfroj2XheGmm;2IOtXfroj2XheGmm'),
(65 ,'!vMHlIDEVTpfTJ;CHn9kvMHlI;DEVTpfTJCHn9kv;MHlIDEVTpfTJCH;n9kvMHl;IDEVTpfTJCHn9kv;MHlIDEVTpfTJCHn9k'),
(66 ,'!H96D9GMYCi35E;D3EEXH96D;9GMYCi35ED3EEXH;96D9GMYCi35ED3;EEXH96;D9GMYCi35ED3EEXH;96D9GMYCi35ED3EEX'),
(67 ,'!YWtJOgJNrfgz1K;eT2yq0YWtJO;gJNrfgz1KeT2yq0Y;WtJOgJNrfgz1KeT2;yq0YWtJ;OgJNrfgz1KeT2yq0Y;WtJOgJNrfgz1KeT2yq0'),
(68 ,'!ZQVoTL3dsqzO;Z2TlwZQVoT;L3dsqzOZ2TlwZ;QVoTL3dsqzOZ2T;lwZQVo;TL3dsqzOZ2TlwZ;QVoTL3dsqzOZ2Tlw'),
(69 ,'!jo9Nq8PP0mQ4E;JKYjTvjo9Nq;8PP0mQ4EJKYjTvj;o9Nq8PP0mQ4EJKY;jTvjo9N;q8PP0mQ4EJKYjTvj;o9Nq8PP0mQ4EJKYjTv'),
(70 ,'!Z2nqrDNyRyQ84E;uWju3Z2nqr;DNyRyQ84EuWju3Z;2nqrDNyRyQ84EuW;ju3Z2nq;rDNyRyQ84EuWju3Z;2nqrDNyRyQ84EuWju3'),
(71 ,'!U7gmZ7s1xCt3yr;oWg2eU7gmZ;7s1xCt3yroWg2eU;7gmZ7s1xCt3yroWg;2eU7gm;Z7s1xCt3yroWg2eU;7gmZ7s1xCt3yroWg2e'),
(72 ,'!kntiDr7Ynih8o;muzCxKknti;Dr7Ynih8omuzCxKk;ntiDr7Ynih8omuz;CxKknt;iDr7Ynih8omuzCxKk;ntiDr7Ynih8omuzCxK'),
(73 ,'!7pjcp4uz2vG;k7gtvk7pjcp;4uz2vGk7gtvk7;pjcp4uz2vGk7g;tvk7pjc;p4uz2vGk7gtvk7;pjcp4uz2vGk7gtvk'),
(74 ,'!IHorwxWIKDiNr;CUhZzKIHorw;xWIKDiNrCUhZzKI;HorwxWIKDiNrCUh;ZzKIHor;wxWIKDiNrCUhZzKI;HorwxWIKDiNrCUhZzK'),
(75 ,'!gwyYPLESe88iP;kqPhYwgwyYP;LESe88iPkqPhYwg;wyYPLESe88iPkqP;hYwgwyY;PLESe88iPkqPhYwg;wyYPLESe88iPkqPhYw'),
(76 ,'!x7R6VZhL0oH7m;KZ7Cyx7R6;VZhL0oH7mKZ7Cyx;7R6VZhL0oH7mKZ;7Cyx7R6;VZhL0oH7mKZ7Cyx;7R6VZhL0oH7mKZ7Cy'),
(77 ,'!LcL1txPN1kuf;cOLN7LcL1t;xPN1kufcOLN7L;cL1txPN1kufcO;LN7LcL1;txPN1kufcOLN7L;cL1txPN1kufcOLN7'),
(78 ,'!JcUHuiGriMH6VX;PXV88JcUHu;iGriMH6VXPXV88J;cUHuiGriMH6VXPX;V88JcUH;uiGriMH6VXPXV88J;cUHuiGriMH6VXPXV88'),
(79 ,'!yTCJ4O7k6VY86;QptQXMyTCJ4;O7k6VY86QptQXMy;TCJ4O7k6VY86Qpt;QXMyTCJ;4O7k6VY86QptQXMy;TCJ4O7k6VY86QptQXM'),
(80 ,'!6LUGRUtmcyTgIp;VxeUdx6LUGR;UtmcyTgIpVxeUdx6;LUGRUtmcyTgIpVxe;Udx6LUG;RUtmcyTgIpVxeUdx6;LUGRUtmcyTgIpVxeUdx'),
(81 ,'!s8pZdUXOQ4DS;HC9flDs8pZd;UXOQ4DSHC9flDs;8pZdUXOQ4DSHC9;flDs8pZ;dUXOQ4DSHC9flDs;8pZdUXOQ4DSHC9flD'),
(82 ,'!Ro8KiK9RlmSv4;P6MYfXRo8Ki;K9RlmSv4P6MYfXR;o8KiK9RlmSv4P6M;YfXRo8K;iK9RlmSv4P6MYfXR;o8KiK9RlmSv4P6MYfX'),
(83 ,'!ln4KCjkLP1I;F49W3lln4K;CjkLP1IF49W3ll;n4KCjkLP1IF49;W3lln4;KCjkLP1IF49W3ll;n4KCjkLP1IF49W3l'),
(84 ,'!S5PL7p27LHUX;w4eQ8S5PL;7p27LHUXw4eQ8S;5PL7p27LHUXw4e;Q8S5PL;7p27LHUXw4eQ8S;5PL7p27LHUXw4eQ8'),
(85 ,'!hYjSnRFpWDz4Z0;0753FShYjSn;RFpWDz4Z00753FSh;YjSnRFpWDz4Z0075;3FShYjS;nRFpWDz4Z00753FSh;YjSnRFpWDz4Z00753FS'),
(86 ,'!NzyIv78oIjy37Z;JYrFXiNzyIv;78oIjy37ZJYrFXiN;zyIv78oIjy37ZJYr;FXiNzyI;v78oIjy37ZJYrFXiN;zyIv78oIjy37ZJYrFXi'),
(87 ,'!Xy76i8qNEIglrI;zkWnS2Xy76i;8qNEIglrIzkWnS2X;y76i8qNEIglrIzkW;nS2Xy76;i8qNEIglrIzkWnS2X;y76i8qNEIglrIzkWnS2'),
(88 ,'!DMgLIM244k9WX;GT2DMgLI;M244k9WXGT2D;MgLIM244k9WXGT;2DMgL;IM244k9WXGT2D;MgLIM244k9WXGT2'),
(89 ,'!fiiufVTuw18e;T6ge1Gfiiu;fVTuw18eT6ge1Gf;iiufVTuw18eT6g;e1Gfii;ufVTuw18eT6ge1Gf;iiufVTuw18eT6ge1G'),
(90 ,'!0gPU45vWcTyCM1;QeUmd0gPU4;5vWcTyCM1QeUmd0;gPU45vWcTyCM1QeU;md0gPU;45vWcTyCM1QeUmd0;gPU45vWcTyCM1QeUmd'),
(91 ,'!1NMV7wleKfJLl4;x14EIs1NMV7;wleKfJLl4x14EIs1;NMV7wleKfJLl4x14;EIs1NMV;7wleKfJLl4x14EIs1;NMV7wleKfJLl4x14EIs'),
(92 ,'!NwIeL4FpcFonk8;53nUGtNwIeL;4FpcFonk853nUGtN;wIeL4FpcFonk853n;UGtNwIe;L4FpcFonk853nUGtN;wIeL4FpcFonk853nUGt'),
(93 ,'!e0hCFCp6POS0;W3mT9Oe0hCF;Cp6POS0W3mT9Oe;0hCFCp6POS0W3m;T9Oe0hC;FCp6POS0W3mT9Oe;0hCFCp6POS0W3mT9O'),
(94 ,'!hicXljjOjW38K;DRiTo0hicXl;jjOjW38KDRiTo0h;icXljjOjW38KDRi;To0hicX;ljjOjW38KDRiTo0h;icXljjOjW38KDRiTo0'),
(95 ,'!Imfqgoi5GFO3e;1ISF0Imfqg;oi5GFO3e1ISF0I;mfqgoi5GFO3e1IS;F0Imfq;goi5GFO3e1ISF0I;mfqgoi5GFO3e1ISF0'),
(96 ,'!vWrPhvZREXoSRf;dJ5eDqvWrPh;vZREXoSRfdJ5eDqv;WrPhvZREXoSRfdJ5;eDqvWrP;hvZREXoSRfdJ5eDqv;WrPhvZREXoSRfdJ5eDq'),
(97 ,'!iP6pXo9Cx5LSE;EiHQ6iP6p;Xo9Cx5LSEEiHQ6i;P6pXo9Cx5LSEEiH;Q6iP6;pXo9Cx5LSEEiHQ6i;P6pXo9Cx5LSEEiHQ6'),
(98 ,'!51FKRpIJ2pl;IslSkw51FKR;pIJ2plIslSkw5;1FKRpIJ2plIsl;Skw51FK;RpIJ2plIslSkw5;1FKRpIJ2plIslSkw'),
(99 ,'!jQITOYz2l3TgiN;7jqYTQjQITO;Yz2l3TgiN7jqYTQj;QITOYz2l3TgiN7jq;YTQjQIT;OYz2l3TgiN7jqYTQj;QITOYz2l3TgiN7jqYTQ'),
(100,'!EWHsSNN5Wpu84x;xVYNtEWHsS;NN5Wpu84xxVYNtE;WHsSNN5Wpu84xxV;YNtEWHs;SNN5Wpu84xxVYNtE;WHsSNN5Wpu84xxVYNt');


-- Unfolding the words
TRUNCATE TABLE test_words_unfolded;
INSERT INTO test_words_unfolded (word, id)
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.words,';', nr.n),';',-1) as word, t.id
FROM test_words AS t
JOIN test_nums AS nr
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(t.words) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t.words,';','')) >= nr.n - 1
 AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.words,';', nr.n),';',-1) != '';

-- SELECT * FROM test_words_unfolded;

-- Building the word list
TRUNCATE TABLE test_wordlist;
INSERT INTO test_wordlist (word) 
SELECT DISTINCT word
FROM test_words_unfolded;

-- SELECT * FROM test_wordlist ORDER BY wordid;

TRUNCATE TABLE test_wordids;
INSERT INTO test_wordids (wordid, id)
SELECT l.wordid, u.id
FROM test_words_unfolded u
JOIN test_wordlist l ON l.word = u.word;

-- SELECT * FROM test_wordids ORDER BY id, wordid;

INSERT INTO test_wordids (id, wordid, idlist)
SELECT q1.id1, t3.wordid, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.id ORDER BY t3.id ASC SEPARATOR ',') as idlist
FROM
(
  SELECT t1.id as id1, t2.id as id2
  FROM test_wordids t1
  JOIN test_wordids t2 ON replace(t1.wordid,'!','') = replace(t2.wordid,'!','') and t1.id <> t2.id
  GROUP BY t1.id, t2.id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) q1
JOIN test_wordids t3 ON t3.id = q1.id2
LEFT JOIN test_wordids t4 ON replace(t4.wordid,'!','') = replace(t3.wordid,'!','') and t4.id = q1.id1
WHERE t4.id is null
GROUP BY q1.id1, t3.wordid;

-- SELECT * FROM test_wordids ORDER BY id, wordid;

TRUNCATE TABLE test_result;
INSERT INTO test_result (id, words)
SELECT 
 wid.id, 
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN wid.idlist IS NULL THEN w.word ELSE CONCAT('{[',wid.idlist,']',w.word,'}') END ORDER BY w.word ASC SEPARATOR '|') as words
FROM test_wordids wid
LEFT JOIN test_wordlist w ON w.wordid = wid.wordid
GROUP BY wid.id
ORDER BY wid.id;

SELECT * FROM test_result ORDER BY id, words;
```

I want to find common values (at least 2 but in this script I put >= 3 ) in ~150000 **UNICODE** CSV records (some records has more than 200 Field) the result is perfect now:

```
id  words
1   !1i7y41DiNlK2|41DiNlK2qCj5n1|i7y41DiNlK2qC|i7y41DiNlK2qCj5n|j5n1i7y|qCj5n1i7y
2   !mVHfE9O8ZNdR|fE9O8ZNdRP5Dsmmm|HfE9O8ZNdRP5Dsmmm|P5DsmmmVH|smmmV|VHfE9O8ZNdRP5D|VHfE9O8ZNdRP5Dsmm
3   !W5rpiQgtYxF|5MyfF5W5rp|5rpiQgtYxF5My|5rpiQgtYxF5MyfF5|fF5W5rp|iQgtYxF5MyfF5W
4   !XeMV3WTIxHD1d|3WTIxHD1d45KUX|45KUXeMV|eMV3WTIxHD1d45|eMV3WTIxHD1d45KU|KUXeMV
5   !ptwj11ir8XrwQ6|11ir8XrwQ6g2zqsp|1ir8XrwQ6g2zqsp|g2zqsptwj1|twj11ir8XrwQ6g2|twj11ir8XrwQ6g2zqs|zqsptwj
6   !H3W7T6f0PVDIT|3W7T6f0PVDITout|3W7T6f0PVDIToutt6n|6f0PVDIToutt6nH|outt6nH3W7T|T6f0PVDIToutt6nH|t6nH3W7
7   !hiwVTM5hEEft7Q|iwVTM5hEEft7QmPU|iwVTM5hEEft7QmPUmW|M5hEEft7QmPUmWh|mPUmWhiwVT|mWhiwV|TM5hEEft7QmPUmWh
8   !K2rdZkwoycyon|2rdZkwoycyonDIJ|2rdZkwoycyonDIJerE|DIJerEK2rd|erEK2rd|ZkwoycyonDIJerEK
9   !RJOis9hvsD37|9hvsD37qRLvQ6R|JOis9hvsD37qRL|JOis9hvsD37qRLvQ6|qRLvQ6RJOis|s9hvsD37qRLvQ6R|vQ6RJOi
10  !OxP7kULjLD0NlX|h5zWOZOxP7k|kULjLD0NlXh5zWOZO|ULjLD0NlXh5zWOZO|WOZOxP7|xP7kULjLD0NlXh5z|xP7kULjLD0NlXh5zWOZ
11  !4sT7DstFFv8ltE|DstFFv8ltEeoGXUr4|eoGXUr4sT7D|sT7DstFFv8ltEeoG|sT7DstFFv8ltEeoGXUr|stFFv8ltEeoGXUr4|XUr4sT7
12  !TjNmpYiNulMX|jNmpYiNulMXTSZ|jNmpYiNulMXTSZQE5|mpYiNulMXTSZQE5T|pYiNulMXTSZQE5T|QE5TjN|TSZQE5TjNm
13  !VqXYl03xvsplje|03xvspljerxocY9V|cY9VqXY|l03xvspljerxocY9V|qXYl03xvspljerxo|qXYl03xvspljerxocY9|rxocY9VqXYl
14  !YCwOJmqdt9F2hH|7fHx1YCwOJ|CwOJmqdt9F2hH7fH|CwOJmqdt9F2hH7fHx1|Jmqdt9F2hH7fHx1Y|mqdt9F2hH7fHx1Y|x1YCwO
15  !HzU3uRnQNVDP|3uRnQNVDPumKkZIH|kZIHzU|umKkZIHzU3|uRnQNVDPumKkZIH|zU3uRnQNVDPumK|zU3uRnQNVDPumKkZI
16  !2ZRXgL4ZxChgw|2x6S2ZRXg|gL4ZxChgw2x6S2|L4ZxChgw2x6S2|x6S2ZRX|ZRXgL4ZxChgw2|ZRXgL4ZxChgw2x6S
17  !UrzHZyuoWW|9C6Urz|HZyuoWWuxV9C6U|rzHZyuoWWuxV|rzHZyuoWWuxV9C6|uxV9C6UrzH|ZyuoWWuxV9C6U
18  !Rs0venylDKQ0F|enylDKQ0FxMNK0oR|K0oRs0v|nylDKQ0FxMNK0oR|s0venylDKQ0FxMN|s0venylDKQ0FxMNK0o|xMNK0oRs0ve
19  !IldIIIJ6VCCi4|IIJ6VCCi4s8W84I|IJ6VCCi4s8W84I|ldIIIJ6VCCi4s8|ldIIIJ6VCCi4s8W84|s8W84IldII|W84IldI
20  !wywvP28fgNoRQ|j2tN0wywv|N0wyw|P28fgNoRQj2tN0w|vP28fgNoRQj2tN0w|ywvP28fgNoRQj2t|ywvP28fgNoRQj2tN0
21  !ukjYiDksZPJ9LE|DksZPJ9LEyOOSLu|iDksZPJ9LEyOOSLu|kjYiDksZPJ9LEyOO|kjYiDksZPJ9LEyOOSL|SLukjY|yOOSLukjYi
22  !mMJFFrXDTEWL|dk5RmcmMJ|FFrXDTEWLdk5Rmcm|JFFrXDTEWLdk5Rmcm|MJFFrXDTEWLdk5|MJFFrXDTEWLdk5Rmc|RmcmM
23  !VVih1wD0KY2np|1wD0KY2npcnqGD1|cnqGD1VVih|GD1VVi|h1wD0KY2npcnqGD1|VVih1wD0KY2npcnq|VVih1wD0KY2npcnqGD1
24  !9H0sIID54YXD|H0sIID54YXDWUi|H0sIID54YXDWUiQtS|IID54YXDWUiQtS9|QtS9H0|sIID54YXDWUiQtS9|WUiQtS9H0s
25  !Mo8ImqgLr4iv1V|2yYMo8I|5Yy2yYMo8Im|mqgLr4iv1V5Yy2yYM|o8ImqgLr4iv1V5Yy|o8ImqgLr4iv1V5Yy2yY|qgLr4iv1V5Yy2yYM
26  !xlW8tEsewe00m|Esewe00myKrtx|lW8tEsewe00myK|lW8tEsewe00myKrt|rtxlW8|tEsewe00myKrtx|yKrtxlW8t
27  !kCP8ch4KOcKY|1HZkCP8|ch4KOcKYMy1HZk|CP8ch4KOcKYMy|CP8ch4KOcKYMy1HZ|h4KOcKYMy1HZk|My1HZkCP8c
28  !7Vod5Qe2s18Wcr|5Qe2s18WcrMtkQCc7|MtkQCc7Vod5|QCc7Vod|Qe2s18WcrMtkQCc7|Vod5Qe2s18WcrMtk|Vod5Qe2s18WcrMtkQCc
29  !0K6INYcK9Q0Q|ehxlZI0K6IN|K6INYcK9Q0Qehx|K6INYcK9Q0QehxlZI|lZI0K6I|NYcK9Q0QehxlZI0|YcK9Q0QehxlZI0
30  !40ORDrXreOkFGj|0ORDrXreOkFGjsCW|0ORDrXreOkFGjsCW6pT|6pT40OR|DrXreOkFGjsCW6pT4|rXreOkFGjsCW6pT4|sCW6pT40ORD
31  !pn22cfCUk7sJlP|cfCUk7sJlPnCQVu3p|fCUk7sJlPnCQVu3p|n22cfCUk7sJlPnCQ|n22cfCUk7sJlPnCQVu3|nCQVu3pn22c|Vu3pn22
32  !weZk4vDOigRWw|2IgOZweZk4|4vDOigRWw2IgOZw|eZk4vDOigRWw2Ig|eZk4vDOigRWw2IgOZ|OZweZk|vDOigRWw2IgOZw
33  !hZqzmLXDJ1My|mLXDJ1MySRipnth|pnthZq|SRipnthZqz|zmLXDJ1MySRipnth|ZqzmLXDJ1MySRi|ZqzmLXDJ1MySRipnt
34  !9omWuMV731VZw|eU9kEh9omWu|kEh9omW|MV731VZweU9kEh9|omWuMV731VZweU9|omWuMV731VZweU9kEh|uMV731VZweU9kEh9
35  !TmeeWHpnTiR5q|116VtgTmeeW|HpnTiR5q116VtgT|meeWHpnTiR5q116|meeWHpnTiR5q116Vtg|VtgTmee|WHpnTiR5q116VtgT
36  !7w8C5Xs0hwHJqm|5Xs0hwHJqmiuZ8m7|iuZ8m7w8C5|w8C5Xs0hwHJqmiu|w8C5Xs0hwHJqmiuZ8m|Xs0hwHJqmiuZ8m7|Z8m7w8C
37  !TUPSnkpxrPCuw|lCKTUPS|nkpxrPCuwZnLlCKT|UPSnkpxrPCuwZnL|UPSnkpxrPCuwZnLlCK|ZnLlCKTUPS
38  !V4kfx3cV0OPg|3GHIXV4kf|4kfx3cV0OPg3G|4kfx3cV0OPg3GHIX|fx3cV0OPg3GHIXV|HIXV4k|x3cV0OPg3GHIXV
39  !1p97s2dc5IeQ|7s2dc5IeQnjEr51|Er51p9|njEr51p97|p97s2dc5IeQnj|p97s2dc5IeQnjEr5|s2dc5IeQnjEr51
40  !OkQHEjQO5dLX|4xCOkQ|EjQO5dLXlFc4xCO|HEjQO5dLXlFc4xCO|kQHEjQO5dLXlFc|kQHEjQO5dLXlFc4xC|lFc4xCOkQH
41  !kLzmTKVXKGGP6s|KVXKGGP6sq2DwDkk|LzmTKVXKGGP6sq2D|LzmTKVXKGGP6sq2DwDk|q2DwDkkLzmT|TKVXKGGP6sq2DwDkk|wDkkLzm
42  !4LN1ZOPGdNvqZ|fW94LN1|ITfW94LN1Z|LN1ZOPGdNvqZIT|LN1ZOPGdNvqZITfW9|OPGdNvqZITfW94|ZOPGdNvqZITfW94
43  !QQKecpk73Hhi|50n7yHQQKec|7yHQQKe|cpk73Hhi50n7yHQ|pk73Hhi50n7yHQ|QKecpk73Hhi50n|QKecpk73Hhi50n7yH
44  !sZTnOtHQqywHs|5NsZT|ewD5NsZTn|nOtHQqywHsewD5Ns|OtHQqywHsewD5Ns|ZTnOtHQqywHsewD|ZTnOtHQqywHsewD5N
45  !i6xS8QT4TUM8wI|6ji6xS|6xS8QT4TUM8wIodz|6xS8QT4TUM8wIodz6j|8QT4TUM8wIodz6ji|odz6ji6xS8|QT4TUM8wIodz6ji
46  !N6V5oSSCQmiks|0J9N6V|5oSSCQmiksrX0J9N|6V5oSSCQmiksrX|6V5oSSCQmiksrX0J9|oSSCQmiksrX0J9N|rX0J9N6V5
47  !mHgLKFf5mO46D|0czmHg|HgLKFf5mO46DLS5|HgLKFf5mO46DLS50cz|KFf5mO46DLS50czm|LKFf5mO46DLS50czm|LS50czmHgL
48  !LgvXdocFztQOXU|cqfLgvX|docFztQOXUlWlcqfL|gvXdocFztQOXUlWl|gvXdocFztQOXUlWlcqf|lWlcqfLgvXd|ocFztQOXUlWlcqfL
49  !7x7dpP86h8Yf|fJtNDF7x7dp|NDF7x7d|P86h8YffJtNDF7|pP86h8YffJtNDF7|x7dpP86h8YffJt|x7dpP86h8YffJtNDF
50  !3F7KsXcsxOJz|7u3F7K|F7KsXcsxOJzj6o|F7KsXcsxOJzj6o7u|j6o7u3F7K|sXcsxOJzj6o7u3
51  !njQLeK6ZxtC9G2|eK6ZxtC9G2q7fKcJn|jQLeK6ZxtC9G2q7f|jQLeK6ZxtC9G2q7fKcJ|K6ZxtC9G2q7fKcJn|KcJnjQL|q7fKcJnjQLe
52  !MP0IG65l6V85o|65l6V85ogOYnMKM|G65l6V85ogOYnMKM|gOYnMKMP0IG|nMKMP0I|P0IG65l6V85ogOY|P0IG65l6V85ogOYnMK
53  !g5uCCirKYxgw|5uCCirKYxgwgP4|5uCCirKYxgwgP4gQW|CirKYxgwgP4gQWg|gP4gQWg5uCC|gQWg5uC|irKYxgwgP4gQWg
54  !uY3PRmvkMqrSg|Ky0Uq7uY3PR|mvkMqrSgKy0Uq7u|RmvkMqrSgKy0Uq7u|Uq7uY3P|Y3PRmvkMqrSgKy0|Y3PRmvkMqrSgKy0Uq7
55  !4JJJekS83VGGo|ekS83VGGotoKNfY4|JJJekS83VGGotoK|JJJekS83VGGotoKNfY|kS83VGGotoKNfY4|NfY4JJJ|toKNfY4JJJe
56  !sw6tmtWc3mHsww|3WRx3sw6tm|mtWc3mHsww3WRx3s|Rx3sw6t|tWc3mHsww3WRx3s|w6tmtWc3mHsww3W|w6tmtWc3mHsww3WRx3
57  !fSjcmnO4FWMLsk|g0CfSjc|Lcng0CfSjcm|mnO4FWMLskLcng0Cf|nO4FWMLskLcng0Cf|SjcmnO4FWMLskLcn|SjcmnO4FWMLskLcng0C
58  !mH3up5F26twSV|1l3gMxmH3up|5F26twSV1l3gMxm|gMxmH3u|H3up5F26twSV1l3|H3up5F26twSV1l3gMx|p5F26twSV1l3gMxm
59  !qEWG2UOxmXKIf|2UOxmXKIfv9mKhCq|EWG2UOxmXKIfv9m|EWG2UOxmXKIfv9mKhC|KhCqEWG|UOxmXKIfv9mKhCq|v9mKhCqEWG2
60  !Zep3Jg60o69k|3Jg60o69kGL2D0|D0Ze|GL2D0Zep|p3Jg60o69kGL2D0|Zep3Jg60o69kGL2|Zep3Jg60o69kGL2D0
61  !Ro5cItK39626iR|0KRo5c|ItK39626iRlKC0KR|lKC0KRo5cI|o5cItK39626iRlKC|o5cItK39626iRlKC0K|tK39626iRlKC0KR
62  !S8UY9k0hJCKIL|8UY9k0hJCKILMfw|8UY9k0hJCKILMfwXsL|9k0hJCKILMfwXsLS|k0hJCKILMfwXsLS|MfwXsLS8UY9|XsLS8UY
63  !cg6xkyMgFRG0H7|g6xkyMgFRG0H7rNw|g6xkyMgFRG0H7rNwJRz|JRzcg6x|kyMgFRG0H7rNwJRzc|rNwJRzcg6xk|yMgFRG0H7rNwJRzc
64  !2IOtXfroj2|2IOtXfroj2Xhe|2IOtXfroj2XheGmm|Gmm2|IOtXfroj2XheGmm|OtXfroj2XheGmm|XheGmm2I
65  !vMHlIDEVTpfTJ|CHn9kvMHlI|DEVTpfTJCHn9kv|IDEVTpfTJCHn9kv|MHlIDEVTpfTJCH|MHlIDEVTpfTJCHn9k|n9kvMHl
66  !H96D9GMYCi35E|96D9GMYCi35ED3|96D9GMYCi35ED3EEX|9GMYCi35ED3EEXH|D3EEXH96D|D9GMYCi35ED3EEXH|EEXH96
67  !YWtJOgJNrfgz1K|eT2yq0YWtJO|gJNrfgz1KeT2yq0Y|OgJNrfgz1KeT2yq0Y|WtJOgJNrfgz1KeT2|WtJOgJNrfgz1KeT2yq0|yq0YWtJ
68  !ZQVoTL3dsqzO|L3dsqzOZ2TlwZ|lwZQVo|QVoTL3dsqzOZ2T|QVoTL3dsqzOZ2Tlw|TL3dsqzOZ2TlwZ|Z2TlwZQVoT
69  !jo9Nq8PP0mQ4E|8PP0mQ4EJKYjTvj|JKYjTvjo9Nq|jTvjo9N|o9Nq8PP0mQ4EJKY|o9Nq8PP0mQ4EJKYjTv|q8PP0mQ4EJKYjTvj
70  !Z2nqrDNyRyQ84E|2nqrDNyRyQ84EuW|2nqrDNyRyQ84EuWju3|DNyRyQ84EuWju3Z|ju3Z2nq|rDNyRyQ84EuWju3Z|uWju3Z2nqr
71  !U7gmZ7s1xCt3yr|2eU7gm|7gmZ7s1xCt3yroWg|7gmZ7s1xCt3yroWg2e|7s1xCt3yroWg2eU|oWg2eU7gmZ|Z7s1xCt3yroWg2eU
72  !kntiDr7Ynih8o|CxKknt|Dr7Ynih8omuzCxKk|iDr7Ynih8omuzCxKk|muzCxKknti|ntiDr7Ynih8omuz|ntiDr7Ynih8omuzCxK
73  !7pjcp4uz2vG|4uz2vGk7gtvk7|k7gtvk7pjcp|p4uz2vGk7gtvk7|pjcp4uz2vGk7g|pjcp4uz2vGk7gtvk|tvk7pjc
74  !IHorwxWIKDiNr|CUhZzKIHorw|HorwxWIKDiNrCUh|HorwxWIKDiNrCUhZzK|wxWIKDiNrCUhZzKI|xWIKDiNrCUhZzKI|ZzKIHor
75  !gwyYPLESe88iP|hYwgwyY|kqPhYwgwyYP|LESe88iPkqPhYwg|PLESe88iPkqPhYwg|wyYPLESe88iPkqP|wyYPLESe88iPkqPhYw
76  !x7R6VZhL0oH7m|7Cyx7R6|7R6VZhL0oH7mKZ|7R6VZhL0oH7mKZ7Cy|KZ7Cyx7R6|VZhL0oH7mKZ7Cyx
77  !LcL1txPN1kuf|cL1txPN1kufcO|cL1txPN1kufcOLN7|cOLN7LcL1t|LN7LcL1|txPN1kufcOLN7L|xPN1kufcOLN7L
78  !JcUHuiGriMH6VX|cUHuiGriMH6VXPX|cUHuiGriMH6VXPXV88|iGriMH6VXPXV88J|PXV88JcUHu|uiGriMH6VXPXV88J|V88JcUH
79  !yTCJ4O7k6VY86|4O7k6VY86QptQXMy|O7k6VY86QptQXMy|QptQXMyTCJ4|QXMyTCJ|TCJ4O7k6VY86Qpt|TCJ4O7k6VY86QptQXM
80  !6LUGRUtmcyTgIp|LUGRUtmcyTgIpVxe|LUGRUtmcyTgIpVxeUdx|RUtmcyTgIpVxeUdx6|Udx6LUG|UtmcyTgIpVxeUdx6|VxeUdx6LUGR
81  !s8pZdUXOQ4DS|8pZdUXOQ4DSHC9|8pZdUXOQ4DSHC9flD|dUXOQ4DSHC9flDs|flDs8pZ|HC9flDs8pZd|UXOQ4DSHC9flDs
82  !Ro8KiK9RlmSv4|iK9RlmSv4P6MYfXR|K9RlmSv4P6MYfXR|o8KiK9RlmSv4P6M|o8KiK9RlmSv4P6MYfX|P6MYfXRo8Ki|YfXRo8K
83  !ln4KCjkLP1I|CjkLP1IF49W3ll|F49W3lln4K|KCjkLP1IF49W3ll|n4KCjkLP1IF49|n4KCjkLP1IF49W3l|W3lln4
84  !S5PL7p27LHUX|5PL7p27LHUXw4e|5PL7p27LHUXw4eQ8|7p27LHUXw4eQ8S|Q8S5PL|w4eQ8S5PL
85  !hYjSnRFpWDz4Z0|0753FShYjSn|3FShYjS|nRFpWDz4Z00753FSh|RFpWDz4Z00753FSh|YjSnRFpWDz4Z0075|YjSnRFpWDz4Z00753FS
86  !NzyIv78oIjy37Z|78oIjy37ZJYrFXiN|FXiNzyI|JYrFXiNzyIv|v78oIjy37ZJYrFXiN|zyIv78oIjy37ZJYr|zyIv78oIjy37ZJYrFXi
87  !Xy76i8qNEIglrI|8qNEIglrIzkWnS2X|i8qNEIglrIzkWnS2X|nS2Xy76|y76i8qNEIglrIzkW|y76i8qNEIglrIzkWnS2|zkWnS2Xy76i
88  !DMgLIM244k9WX|2DMgL|GT2DMgLI|IM244k9WXGT2D|M244k9WXGT2D|MgLIM244k9WXGT|MgLIM244k9WXGT2
89  !fiiufVTuw18e|e1Gfii|fVTuw18eT6ge1Gf|iiufVTuw18eT6g|iiufVTuw18eT6ge1G|T6ge1Gfiiu|ufVTuw18eT6ge1Gf
90  !0gPU45vWcTyCM1|45vWcTyCM1QeUmd0|5vWcTyCM1QeUmd0|gPU45vWcTyCM1QeU|gPU45vWcTyCM1QeUmd|md0gPU|QeUmd0gPU4
91  !1NMV7wleKfJLl4|7wleKfJLl4x14EIs1|EIs1NMV|NMV7wleKfJLl4x14|NMV7wleKfJLl4x14EIs|wleKfJLl4x14EIs1|x14EIs1NMV7
92  !NwIeL4FpcFonk8|4FpcFonk853nUGtN|53nUGtNwIeL|L4FpcFonk853nUGtN|UGtNwIe|wIeL4FpcFonk853n|wIeL4FpcFonk853nUGt
93  !e0hCFCp6POS0|0hCFCp6POS0W3m|0hCFCp6POS0W3mT9O|Cp6POS0W3mT9Oe|FCp6POS0W3mT9Oe|T9Oe0hC|W3mT9Oe0hCF
94  !hicXljjOjW38K|DRiTo0hicXl|icXljjOjW38KDRi|icXljjOjW38KDRiTo0|jjOjW38KDRiTo0h|ljjOjW38KDRiTo0h|To0hicX
95  !Imfqgoi5GFO3e|1ISF0Imfqg|F0Imfq|goi5GFO3e1ISF0I|mfqgoi5GFO3e1IS|mfqgoi5GFO3e1ISF0|oi5GFO3e1ISF0I
96  !vWrPhvZREXoSRf|dJ5eDqvWrPh|eDqvWrP|hvZREXoSRfdJ5eDqv|vZREXoSRfdJ5eDqv|WrPhvZREXoSRfdJ5|WrPhvZREXoSRfdJ5eDq
97  !iP6pXo9Cx5LSE|EiHQ6iP6p|P6pXo9Cx5LSEEiH|P6pXo9Cx5LSEEiHQ6|pXo9Cx5LSEEiHQ6i|Q6iP6|Xo9Cx5LSEEiHQ6i
98  !51FKRpIJ2pl|1FKRpIJ2plIsl|1FKRpIJ2plIslSkw|IslSkw51FKR|pIJ2plIslSkw5|RpIJ2plIslSkw5|Skw51FK
99  !jQITOYz2l3TgiN|7jqYTQjQITO|OYz2l3TgiN7jqYTQj|QITOYz2l3TgiN7jq|QITOYz2l3TgiN7jqYTQ|YTQjQIT|Yz2l3TgiN7jqYTQj
100     !EWHsSNN5Wpu84x|NN5Wpu84xxVYNtE|SNN5Wpu84xxVYNtE|WHsSNN5Wpu84xxV|WHsSNN5Wpu84xxVYNt|xVYNtEWHsS|YNtEWHs
```

At first I had many Problems with mysql (connection Timeout and error) thus I added these to my.cnf|my.ini :

```
default-storage-engine=InnoDB
wait_timeout = 28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
key_buffer_size=32M
max_allowed_packet=4096M
group_concat_max_len = 1000000

innodb_strict_mode=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_strict_mode=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_file_size = 1024M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
```

Another problem was low width string in column thus I added varchar(1000) but Mysql gives an error again and I changed to varchar(500).

Now the result is very good for me but

1-It is slow

2-because I have a ! at first of my first column script some times put repeated values in my result that I don't want the same value with ! or {.

3-I Don't know which line is in process (I have not any counter for process recognizing)

4-If I stop I have no any data in the Result table, It save the data at the end

Comment: How much RAM?  (I'm worried that you have set some of the tunables too high.)

Comment: Is it important whether a pair of words are in the same line?  Do these lines have a consistent number of "words" (maybe 6?)?

Comment: @rick-james 8G ram X64

Comment: Not sure why you join like this `ON replace(t4.wordid,'!','') = replace(t3.wordid,'!','')`. Aren't those wordid's just numbers, and using a function to join could ignore the use of an index?

Answer (score 0):

This is an algorithm problem, not a MySQL schema and tuning problem.

However, here are some tips:

- Every table needs a `PRIMARY KEY`.
- Don't over-normalize.  In particular, `word` should not be normalized.
- Use a programming language, not SQL for splitting text up.  Most languages have very efficient 'split' or 'explode' functions.
- The dataset (a few million words) can be easily handled in programming languages.  The code will be much more efficient there (versus SQL).

Comment: Maybe @LukStorms can help me for normalizing

Comment: @RickJames Just FYI. The original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53085840/4003419) from SmmSamm was actually looking for any solution, sql or not, that could solve it fast enough. It's a rather tricky programming puzzle when you're dealing with so much data as he has.